# Watch property in data issue vue2JS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, watch

Hey I'm currently trying to watch number from data object which is changed by user in input and then multiply it by 4. My code is:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    numberWatched: 1,
    numberAfter: 1
  },
  watch: {
    numberWatched: (val) => {
      this.numberAfter = this.numberWatched * 4;
    }
  }
})
```

`numberWatched` is as `v-model` to input so user can actually change it from UI.

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="number"
         v-model="numberWatched"
         min="0"
         />
  <p>
    {{ numberAfter }}
  </p>
</div>
```

This doesn't work, numberAfter is not multiplied by 4. How to fix? [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xknkvz99/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use `this` when you are using arrow functions. Because vuejs thinks `this` refers to the function and not vue js. so, change you watch object to this:

```
  watch: {
    numberWatched: function (val) {
      this.numberAfter = this.numberWatched * 4;
    }
  }
```

Checkout the working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xknkvz99/1/)